# Unable to increase 'open files' limit in 16.10

Tags: security, process, ulimit

I'm trying to increase the 'open files' to both a regular user and to root user. Been applying different procedures from different sources without success. I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 with Linux 4.8.0-41-generic, and these are the changes I've made so far:

```
$ grep nofile /etc/security/limits.conf 
#        - nofile - max number of open files
root     - nofile       80000
*        - nofile       80000

$ grep pam_limits /etc/pam.d/*
/etc/pam.d/common-session:session required  pam_limits.so
/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive:session    required    pam_limits.so
...
/etc/pam.d/login:session    required   pam_limits.so
...

$ grep file-max /etc/sysctl.conf 
fs.file-max=80000

$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
80000
```

I've then rebooted. After reboot when I check with 'ulimit':

```
$ ulimit -Sn
1024
$ ulimit -Hn
4096
```

Comment: If you log into your machine through ssh, the limit would be bigger. But it does not work for regular login. Same thing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Does Ubuntu v16.10 use systemd?
Then you may be running into the problem where graphical logins are started by systemd which doesn't use /etc/security/limits*.
See this answer instead:

https://superuser.com/a/1322187/116705