# Unable to increase open files hard/soft limits on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, ulimit

I am trying to increase the hard/soft open files limit on an Ubuntu 22.04

After reviewing questions such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/890934/1742985), [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370652/570863) or [that one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1326406/1742985) and tutos such as [this one](https://manishrjain.com/increase-open-file-limits-ubuntu) or [that one](https://linuxhint.com/increase-open-file-limit-ubuntu/), I have made the following changes to my system:

1. Modify `/etc/security/limits.conf` to include two lines

```
* soft nofile 8192
* hard nofile 8192
```

2. Created `/etc/security/limits.d/10-openfiles.conf` with that same two lines

```
* soft nofile 8192
* hard nofile 8192
```

3. Added `session required        pam_limits.so` to `/etc/pam.d/common-session*`
4. Uncommented `DefaultLimitNOFILE` on the section `[Manager]` of `/etc/systemd/user.conf` and set it to 8192
5. Uncommented `DefaultLimitNOFILE` on the section `[Manager]` of `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and set it to 8192
6. systemctl daemon-reexec then reboot (init 6)

No matter what, `ulimit -Sn` shows 1024  and `ulimit -Hn` shows 1048576

`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` is **huge**, 9223372036854775807

That makes me think there must be another config file taking precedence...

System is an Azure VM with an standard Ubuntu 22 server image

Any help greatly appreciated

**UPDATE**

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/451384) points to a user-related config file in /home or /etc/profile.d/ but both `grep -rnw '/etc/profile.d/' -e '1048576'` and `grep -rnw '/home/' -e '1048576'` show empty results

**UPDATE 2**

`cat /proc/sys/fs/nr_open` shows 1048576, so I guess that's from where the hard limit is coming.
Question remains, though. How can I change the soft limit to 8192 files?